# How to get the string content of text() widgets and give the styling below image shown in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, text, flutter-layout

[I want this type of output using single Text() widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft5GR.png)

I am getting data from Api and i get gender from it so i just want to highlight that value by bold it on which gender i get from Api

example:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWqRa.png)

Comment: Do you want to place text over an image?

Comment: no i just want to show that text of on which i get

Answer (score 0):

```
RichText(
    text: TextSpan(
        text: "Female/",
        children: [
            TextSpan(text: "Male",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
        ]
    ),
),
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `Text()` widget inside a `Row()` and provide separate styling.

```
return Row(
 children : [
  Text('Female'),
  Text('/'),
  Text('Male',
   style: TextStyle(
      fontWeight:FontWeight.bold, 
    ),
   ),
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code use [**`RichText`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html)

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'Female',
    style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
    children: const <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(
        text: '/',
      ),
      TextSpan(
        text: 'Male',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Result Screen->[image]

Comment: can you please check that updated question